# Laravel relationships foreach loop

Tags: php, html, laravel

Hello i have a user model and a task model each user can have many tasks therefore i created the user model with a task hasMany relation. But when i try to get the task results from the user model i end up with and error the only way i can avoid this error is by looping through both the user model and the user->task but i can not have 2 loops on my page since this will screw the hole html up so i need to get all of the result from both the user model and the tasks model in one foreach is that possible? code below:

Important part of Model user:

```
protected $table = 'users';
protected $hidden = ['password', 'remember_token'];
protected $fillable = ['email', 'password', 'firstname', 'lastname', 'image'];
protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];
protected $appends = ['name'];
protected $metaModel = UserMeta::class;

public function tasks(){
    return $this->hasMany(UserTask::class);
}
```

Important part of Model Tasks:

```
protected $table = 'user_task';

public function user(){
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

Important part of Task controller:

```
 public function index()
{
    $getUsers = User::all();
    $projects = Project::all();
    $today = Carbon::today('Europe/London');
    $week = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $today)->format('W');
    return view('calender.employee-availability',compact('getUsers','week','projects'));
}
```

Important part of view:

```
 @foreach($getUsers as $user)
      <div class="user-calender">
          <div class="user-info">
            <p>{{ $user->firstname." ".$user->lastname }}</p>
          </div>
          <div class="days">
              <li>M</li>
              <li>T</li>
              <li>O</li>
              <li>T</li>
              <li>F</li>
          </div>

          <div class="hours hour-1">
            <p>{{ $user->tasks->user_id }}</p> **Error is here**
```

Please tell me if i could provide you guys with anything else. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You try to access the property `user_id` from the list of all tasks, so you should either write a loop over all tasks, or access a single task, e.g. `$user->tasks->first()->user_id`.

Comment: Thank you for you answer. Is there really no other way i can get the the tables for the tasks model then looping through?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "tables for the tasks model"

Comment: My mistake i see now that i was unclear i mean the rows in my tasks database for example user_id

Comment: As I said, you either need to write a loop or you access one task directly. I don't see another way.